# Using nosql for rating sytem

Tags: database, relational-database, amazon-dynamodb, rating-system, nosql

I am building a platform where users can rate a musicians song. I have been using AWS mobile which only builds in dynamodb but no relational databases.

I am just wondering whether is is possible to use a nosql database for the song rating purpose.

I can see that i would have a table for songs and for each song I could have a large number of votes but then how would I go about giving ownership of that vote to the user.

Thanks

Comment: please describe you queries you are going to use. specify your table (desired) scheme , etc..

Comment: Hi @Eyal Ch, The schema I wrote out was for a relational database. Basically the most important queries would be for users (sum of ratings/number of ratings given). For the song it would be the same (sum of the ratings for song divided by the number number or ratings). I was thinking that I could have a ratings databse and use a lamda function once every couple of hours to update the overall rating.

Comment: so something like: tbl_song (id, name, sum_rate, num_rate) ??

Comment: Yep basically thats it